# Logging into a website with CURL PHP not working

Tags: php, curl, authentication, web-scraping, yii2

I have a problem logging in to a website with CURL and PHP.

I test with the Firefox add-on HttpRequester and this worked.

Result login:

```
POST https://www.balatarin.com/sessions
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
session[login]=testeruni&session[password]=123456789&session[remember_me]=1&commit=%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF&utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token[![httprequester][1]][1]
 -- response --
200 OK
Server:  shield
Date:  Thu, 19 Jan 2017 13:51:54 GMT
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=utf-8
status:  200 OK
X-Frame-Options:  SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:  1; mode=block
x-ua-compatible:  IE=Edge,chrome=1
Etag:  W/"7418542e936fbdfe20002faf11876845"
Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
Set-Cookie:  _balat_session_new=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--2c2a72f8ec27564250ba084d97998aefba4af11a; path=/; secure; HttpOnly geo=0
X-Request-Id:  521288561d7cfff0ef8fe8d72080760c
X-Runtime:  0.188862
X-Rack-Cache:  miss
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Via:  1.1 google
Alt-Svc:  clear
Expires:  Thu, 19 Jan 2017 13:51:54 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy:  h2
```

[image: HttpRequester]

but it does not login with curl in PHP. I tested all headers in my CURL but it does not login, only works with HttpRequester.

```
public function actionLoggin()
    {
        $url = 'https://www.balatarin.com/sessions';

        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $headers[] = 'Host: www.balatarin.com';
        $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0';
        $headers[] = 'Referer: https://www.balatarin.com/login';

        $params = array(
            'session[login]' => 'testeruni',
            'session[password]' => '123456789',
            'session[remember_me]' => '0',
            'commit' => 'ورود',
            'utf8' => '✓',
            'authenticity_token' => '',
        );

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'bala_cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'bala_cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $result;
    }
```

Here is my cookie file:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.balatarin.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   logged_in   1
#HttpOnly_www.balatarin.com FALSE   /   TRUE    0   _balat_session_new  BAh7CToOcmV0dXJuX3RvMDoMdXNlcl9pZGkDj60BOhJsb2dpbl9yZXRyaWVzMEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTgwN2ZmMDRjMGUzMzkyMDIyZWY5YzBmZTQxN2FmZWMzBjsIVA%3D%3D--d47dd61bc9900449cca69ebd727041c3946a13ba
www.balatarin.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   geo 0
www.balatarin.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   1516368886  corr    b8ed93fa279a469a637b
```

Comment: What's the response from your request? Message? Status code? You might know this, but you can't login to a site from PHP and expect the browser to be logged in after that. PHP is executed on the server (which is the one that will be logged in) and has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: I expect your cookie jar is not working. Can we see the contents of `bala_cookie.txt`?

Comment: i get HTTP/1.1 200 OK but dont login.

Comment: How do you check if you're logged in?

Comment: `logged_in 1`, isn't that the status of your log in? It's hard to for us to know since we don't have a non-logged in vs logged in cookie to compare.

Comment: i login in other website(with csrf token and more,...) but dont login this website.

Comment: So the cookie you linked to isn't for this site? Otherwise, you get a cookie with the CNAME `logged_in` set to `1`, which indicates that you _did_ successfully log in. What is the cookie _suppose_ to look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133561/discussion-between-user3770797-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: ^ @user3770797: if your question is not clear to readers, opening a chat window is not an ideal solution on its own. The best thing to do is to make the question clearer. What do the cookies look like in HttpRequester, and how do they differ from the cURL versions?

Comment: i think you construct the session data in the POST request very wrong for http_build_query. you want `'session'=>array('login'=>'testeruni','password'=>'123456789','remember_me'=>'0')` , not `'session[login]' => 'testeruni',
            'session[password]' => '123456789',
            'session[remember_me]' => '0',`